# How to Write TestCase in Java for this Service?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, jmockit

I have a this class

```
public class AuthenticationModule {

    String userName = "foo";
    String password = "bar";

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
         this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password ) {
         this.password = password ;
    }

    AuthenticationServicePort authenticationServicePort;
    AuthenticationService port;

    private boolean authenicate(String userName, String password) {

        authenticationServicePort = new AuthenticationServicePort();
        port = authenticationServicePort.getAuthenticationServiceProxy();
        return port.login(userName, password);
    }

    public boolean validateUser() {

        return authenicate(userName, password);
    }
}
```

and `AuthenticationServicePort` returns a WSDL port
I want to create a simple test case with a Mock `AuthenticationServicePort` which will return a 'true/false' value

How do I inject in my own `MockObject` without changing the java code?
Or worse case scenario, what is the easiest way to change to be be more easily testable.

Comment: Please go for Easymock-powermock and first try yourself,in case of problems people over here can always help

Comment: Is `AuthenticationServicePort` your own class, or something from a library that you can't change?  If it's the latter, does it implement in interface or extend an abstract class, so that you could create another class with the same methods that implements/extends the same interface/abstract class?

Comment: It is from a library and it does not extend or implement a class/interface. AuthenicationService is an interface, which I was hoping to Mock up, but my problem seems to be the hardcoded 'authenticationServicePort = new AuthenticationServicePort();'

Comment: Then you may need to create a "wrapper" class that implements an interface.  The wrapper class would contain an `AuthenticationServicePort` as a private field, and methods of that class _could_ basically just be calls to the same method on `AuthenticationServicePort` (there's no reason that the interface has to be exactly the same, though).  Another class that implements the same interface would then implement the same methods as mocks.  Then you'd declare `authenticationServicePort` to be your new interface, and inject an instance of that interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example test where `AuthenticationServicePort` is mocked, using JMockit 1.13:

```
public class AuthenticationModuleTest
{
    @Tested AuthenticationModule authentication;
    @Mocked AuthenticationServicePort authenticationService;
    @Mocked AuthenticationService port;

    @Test
    public void validateUser()
    {
        final String userName = "tester";
        final String password = "12345";
        authentication.setUserName(userName);
        authentication.setPassword(password);
        new Expectations() {{ port.login(userName, password); result = true; }};

        boolean validated = authentication.validateUser();

        assertTrue(validated);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid creating instances of classes which have any logic inside (not plain DTO objects). Instead you should design your classes in such a way that dependency injection container can build up complete graph of objects. In your code you need to answer yourself if each call of `authenicate` method does need a new instance of `AuthenticationServicePort`? If yes then you should use a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern to create instances of this object and this factory should be injected (provided in constructor) so you can mock it and everything it will produce. If many calls of `authenticate` method can reuse same instance of `AuthenticationServicePort` then simply inject it (provide in constructor) and in your test provide mock instead of real implementation.